# CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB") doesn't compatible with en-US date format but fines with others

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization

Why the first line of code throws **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."** exception?

en-GB seems not compatible with en-US but strangely enough compatible with zh-CN and ru-RU date format string.

Yes I could simply change the culture info to en-US to make it compatible with en-US date format string. But my question is why en-GB works with zh-CN and ru-RU format strings?

any ideas?

```
        var obj = DateTime.Parse("11/20/2013 3:10:36 AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0809).DateTimeFormat);//en-US
        obj = DateTime.Parse("2013/11/20 3:16:08", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0809).DateTimeFormat);//zh-CN
        obj = DateTime.Parse("20.11.2013 3:17:44", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0809).DateTimeFormat); //ru-RU
```

**0x0809**  en-GB   English (United Kingdom)    English

Thanks,

Comment: Why is that surprising? The UK uses a day/month/year format, whereas the US uses a month/day/year format. They're definitely different.

Comment: then why the same culture info works with date format string in zh-CN and ru-RU?

Comment: Well the Russian form is already similar to the UK one, just using a different delimiter. And the Chinese one is obviously starting with the year... presumably it guesses from that that the month comes next. When you've got two two-digit values next to each other, I suspect it tries to use the culture-specific "normal" ordering of month and day.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` is Really Messed Up™. It tries hard to interpret your string, and can pretty easily get it wrong with you being none the wiser. Use `DateTime.ParseExact` when possible.

Answer (score 10):

You have specified that you are expecting a `DateFormat` in `en-GB` which is usually in the format `dd/MM/yyyy ...` and it is trying to create a date with a Month value of 20, which does not exist.

If you change your expected input format to `en-US` it will work and your internal date will be correct. You can then output it to the `en-GB` format if you wish

```
var obj = DateTime.Parse("11/20/2013 3:10:36 AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat);//en-US
string s = obj.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat); //20/11/2013 03:10:36
```

Comment: I understand it. but It doesn't make sense to me why the en-GB culture info works with date format string in zh-CN and ru-RU which have the totally different format than that of en-GB.

Comment: The en-GB parsing will accept a few different formats, and delimiters. What matters most is the order of the date-parts in the string.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that en-GB is compatible with zh-CN because that format is identical to the ISO standard.  Then it is compatible with ru-RU because the only difference is the delimiter.  The U.S. format is neither-nor, pretty typical it seems.  The parser should (but I haven't checked) always successfully parse the ISO format (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss), and it's the best case use for cross-language data models.